Is it safe to convert emails with other characters than a-Z to lower case?
Any modern email service provider treats emails as case insensitive meaning that in my application I should allows users to log in both using johndoe@gmail.com and JohnDoe@Gmail.com.
In terms of the characters a-Z this is easy to implement as I can just always convert the input to lower case.
However, if a user's email contains other characters like the german ß which converts to SS in uppercase (which would convert back to ss in lowercase), or other international characters which may have special rules for how they convert between lower and upper case, then do I now run the risk of users not being able to log in if they type the email in a different "case" than the one they originally signed up with?
Would it be better to use toLocaleLowerCase() in my scenario then? Or should I only convert the a-Z characters and leave the others in the case they were provided in? Or what should I do in this scenario?
My current implementation is simply (pseudocode):
// when storing the email on my DB
db.user.save({ email: inputEmail.toLowerCase(), ... })

// when finding the user to authenticate
db.user.find("email", inputEmail.toLowerCase())


A complete tangent, but something to consider is the collation used in the database itself, then your code at every point where you interact with the database doesn't need to worry about it.

What database are you using. Does it automatically do case-insensitive searches?

I am using MongoDB @phuzi

Do that for all languages. Users may try different ways each time. You can use unorm library

Why do you want to change the way the user adds their mail address? To me, it would look strange if I add JohnDoe@gmail.com and you convert it to anything else I haven't used

@Nico OTOH, it'd also be strange for one user with one email address to be able to sign up for multiple accounts, just by capitalising their email differently.

@NicoHaase because if you try to log in using johndoe@gmail.com after having registered with JohnDoe@gmail.com you would end up being told that there is no account registered with that email which is not consistent with how modern email service providers handles it

Sidenote: props for considering this problem at all, instead of just pretending that all email addresses only contain some arbitrarily selected subset of ASCII.

@deceze I read Nico's comment more than it'd be odd if the address is displayed in the UI differently to how it was originally entered etc - even more so for anything that falls into the "ExpertsExchange" type of camp where losing capitals causes additional confusion...

I think it could be fine to compare the entered addressed in lower-cased form to a lower-cased form of the address in the database to avoid signing into different accounts (AFAIK MySQL unique indexes can circumnvent this, such that you can't enter the same string with different cases in multiple rows). But storing any other string than the one I've entered would make me wonder

Keep in mind: for us techies, it might be obvious that both addresses are technically equal. Someone less firm, like your grandma, would maybe not understand that your form simply won't accept her mail address like she's used it for years

What exactly is the problem here? If the user provided the same email address for both registration and login, then .toLowerCase() will produce the same string. And why is, converting to upper then lower not resulting in the original characters, a problem? You aren't converting to upper case in your example and I don't see any need to.

Also certain email providers can have email addresses in multiple forms. i.e. john.doe+somehing@gmail.com, john.doe@gmail.com, johndoe@gmail.com and j.o.h.n.d.o.e@gmail.com are all email addresses from the same Gmail account.

@gre_gor I only used the german ß as my example as I know a little german and I don't know any other specific example, but there are of course tens of thousands of characters which I have no clue how would behave like for example Chinese or Arabic characters

A better example of a problem would be, if you used upper case for case insensitive match. In that case "Strauß@example.com" and "Strauss@example.com" would match, but the mail server might consider them as different accounts.

Well, you can either do storedEmail.toLowerCase() === inputEmail.toLowercase() during signup/sign in, or with each character input you can instantly lower case it (like <input value={inputEmail.toLowerCase()} onChange={setInputEmail} />. For multiple languages you can use toLocaleLowerCase(), I have never used it but it converts a string to lowercase letters using the current locale, which is based on the browser's language settings

"would match, but the mail server might consider them as different accounts" - you'll never know what exactly arbitrary mail servers will consider as the same mailbox or not. "meaning that in my application I should allows users to log in both" - no. You only need to allow login under the same address as was used for signup. Store that in your database, not something else. It's also the address you will need to use when actually sending an email - do not change its case!


Any modern email service provider treats emails as case insensitive.

Yes.

Though if you used upper case for case insensitive match, Strauß@example.com and Strauss@example.com would match, but the mail server might consider them as different accounts.

You'll never know what exactly arbitrary mail servers will consider as the same mailbox or not.

… meaning that in my application I should allows users to log in both

No. You only need to allow login under the same address as was used for signup. Store that in your database, not something else. It's also the address you will need to use when actually sending an email - do not change its case! To answer the title question, it is never safe to convert email address to a different case, regardless whether you do it only for the characters [a-z] or not.
However, unrelated to the email address stored in the user profile, you may want to allow logins when the user enters a similar-enough email for convenience. Here, you can make up arbitrary rules, as long as "strauss" logs into the actual Strauß@example.com account. Of course that means you will have to also prevent users from creating accounts with similar email addresses, but you're safe as long as you follow the same (arbitrary) normalisation rules for uniqueness checking. Notice it's also a good idea to prevent homoglyph attacks, especially if the email address is displayed to the public or any other user.

Ok, so if I understand correctly, I should always store the email as it was provided. Then, both during sign up and sign in, I can make my own rules for what constitutes uniqueness as long as the same rules apply in both scenarios?

Yes, thought the rules could be different. For signup of a second account, the matching could be less strict (i.e. treat more values as similar to existing accounts) than for login. What the rules need to prevent is getting a login that would match multiple accounts.
